Slowly scrollable with multiple plots in Tkinter
The primary problem here is when plotting too much data (~36 subplots) using FigureCanvasTkAgg the Scrollbar of Tkinter being too sluggish and slow when the user is scrolling. Is there any solution to this problem, I don't want my user to experience this. Thanks.
You can try this code here:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Scrollable Matplotlib Plot with 9 Subplots")

        # Create a frame for the canvas and scrollbars
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create a canvas for the Matplotlib figure
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create vertical scrollbar
        self.v_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.v_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Create horizontal scrollbar
        self.h_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.h_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

        # Configure canvas with scrollbars
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.v_scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.h_scrollbar.set)

        # Create a figure and multiple subplots
        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(6, 6, figsize=(10, 10))  # 3x3 grid of subplots

        # Generate some data for the plots
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        for i, ax in enumerate(self.axs.flat):
            ax.plot(x, np.sin(x + i), label=f'Sine Wave {i+1}')
            ax.set_title(f'Plot {i+1}')
            ax.legend()

        # Add the Matplotlib figure to the canvas
        self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.canvas)
        self.figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Bind the canvas to scrolling
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.figure_canvas.get_tk_widget(), anchor='nw')

        # Update the scroll region
        self.update_scroll_region()

        # Bind the resize event to update scroll region
        self.root.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)

    def update_scroll_region(self):
        """Update the scroll region based on the canvas content."""
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_resize(self, event):
        """Update the scroll region when the window is resized."""
        self.update_scroll_region()

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()


how about instead of having 36 subplots in 1 canvas you have 36 canvases in 1 widget, this way canvases don't need to redraw while scrolling, you are just hitting how fast matplotlib can work on the CPU, alternatively you can store the result plot as an image and just show that instead.

what do you mean by 36 canvases? My app needs to contain many plots, and my users want it scrollable to see it all, it cannot show multiple subplots in one window. That's hard for me to solve this problem.

And you said "plot as an image" I have never done that, is there a difference between "return a dynamically a fig containing multiple plots" and "image of subplots"? And if I save it as an image then it is impossible to resize the plot (again) like this: self.plt.set_size_inches(new_figsize) because my user can dynamically resize the grid of the plot too in the application.

The third problem is user cannot use the NavigationToolbar2Tk too if I save it as image buffer

the bottleneck here is that whenever the canvas gets redrawn it forces an unnecessary redraw on the underlying matplotlib plot which didn't need to get updated, subclassing FigureCanvasTkAgg and preventing the redraw of the matplotlib plot when scrolling could help, but the whole thing is not synchronous so a lot of trickery needs to be applied.

in other words, you cannot just do if not scrolling(): draw(), you need more like if was_scrolling(): skip_the first_redraw_that_will_happen_in_the_future() .... which is very bug prone.

I'm sorry to say that I don't know what you said: "the bottleneck here is that whenever the canvas gets redrawn it forces an unnecessary redraw on the underlying matplotlib plot which didn't need to get updated...". I assumed just the scroll element is being updated not the canvas, isn't it?

The slowdown is caused by the scrollbar triggering an unnecessary redraw of the underlying matplotlib plot, and matplotlib is slow, i think this could be fixed on matplotlib side, but you could work around it.
You can skip the matplotlib redraw by subclassing the FigureCanvasTkAgg and skipping the next redraw if the canvas is being scrolled, since the redraw happens in the future, not inside the scrolling callback.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
import time

class SkippableFigureCanvas(FigureCanvasTkAgg):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self._skip_redraw = False
    def skip_redraw(self):
        self._skip_redraw = True
    def draw(self):
        if self._skip_redraw:
            self._skip_redraw = False
            return
        super().draw()


class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Scrollable Matplotlib Plot with 9 Subplots")
        self.last_update_time = time.time()
        # Create a frame for the canvas and scrollbars
        frame = tk.Frame(root)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create a canvas for the Matplotlib figure
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create vertical scrollbar
        self.v_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.v_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Create horizontal scrollbar
        self.h_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.h_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

        def my_h_scroll_command(*args):
            self.figure_canvas.skip_redraw()
            self.canvas.xview(*args)
        def my_v_scroll_command(*args):
            self.figure_canvas.skip_redraw()
            self.canvas.yview(*args)
        self.v_scrollbar.configure(command=my_v_scroll_command)
        self.h_scrollbar.configure(command=my_h_scroll_command)

        # Configure canvas with scrollbars
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.v_scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.h_scrollbar.set)

        # Create a figure and multiple subplots
        self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(6, 6, figsize=(10, 10))  # 3x3 grid of subplots

        # Generate some data for the plots
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        for i, ax in enumerate(self.axs.flat):
            ax.plot(x, np.sin(x + i), label=f'Sine Wave {i+1}')
            ax.set_title(f'Plot {i+1}')
            ax.legend()

        # Add the Matplotlib figure to the canvas
        self.figure_canvas = SkippableFigureCanvas(self.fig, master=self.canvas)
        self.figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Bind the canvas to scrolling
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.figure_canvas.get_tk_widget(), anchor='nw')

        # Update the scroll region
        self.update_scroll_region()

        # Bind the resize event to update scroll region
        self.root.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)

    def update_scroll_region(self):
        """Update the scroll region based on the canvas content."""
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
    def on_resize(self, event):
        """Update the scroll region when the window is resized."""
        self.update_scroll_region()

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()

the new parts are the SkippableFigureCanvas which allows you to skip drawing the next matplotlib plot when needed, and this next part which attaches a callback that is called whenever the user moves the scrollbar to skip the next redraw of the matplotlib plot.
def my_h_scroll_command(*args):
    self.figure_canvas.skip_redraw()
    self.canvas.xview(*args)
def my_v_scroll_command(*args):
    self.figure_canvas.skip_redraw()
    self.canvas.yview(*args)
self.v_scrollbar.configure(command=my_v_scroll_command)
self.h_scrollbar.configure(command=my_h_scroll_command)

Note that the above "work around" may break things in the future if matplotlib "fixes" it on their side, use at your own risk, it is also bug-prone if you update the plot while the user is scrolling it ... so don't write code that updates the plot while scrolling, it could also break if you have animations or other things that update the plot over time. (you might need to manually call Draw to force an update)
